# solr5.1: Json facet: range facet query in combination with blockjoin doesnt work

Tags: solr, facet, solr5

Below is my schema structure:

```
Doc1:
  id: A1_1,
  name: xyz,
  type: A1,
  field5:TTT,
  _childDocuments_:Doc4,Doc5

Doc4:
     id: A2_1
     type:A2
     field1: ABC,
     field2: DEF,
     field3: TVF,
     field4: 2014-02-01T00:00:00Z
```

Doc5 is similar in structure as Doc4.

I am using json-facets. Below is my query

```
  json.facet = {
      a1: {
        type: terms,
        field: range,
        start: "NOW/YEAR-2YEAR",
        end: "NOW/YEAR%2B2YEAR",
        gap: "%2B1MONTH",
        mincount: 1,
        limit: 100,
        facet: {
          a2: {
            type: terms,
            field: field1,
            facet: {
               a3:{
                 type: terms,
                 field: field2,
                 facet:{
                   a4: {
                     type: terms,
                     field: field5,
                     domain: {blockParent: {"type:A1"}}
                   } 
                 }
               }
            }   
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

If i dont use the range query and just start my query from the `**a2**` part of the query above, it fetches results as expected. Similarly if I run the above query, all results till the `blockParent` do come but `blockParent` related facet results dont come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facets on nested docs don't work fine until 5.3. Upgrade to solr5.3 to verify (you can just install solr5.3, then copy the index there and you should be able to run such queries.

I encountered this same issue, for more details [check out my post](https://medium.com/@jmlucjav/using-solr-s-dataimporthandler-and-updaterequestprocessor-in-elasticsearch-2-0-596eb6e3a483), you can see even more complex json facet queries working on nested docs.